# Ember.js and jQuery Sortable. How to work around the metamorph scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, ember.js, jquery-ui-sortable

I have an ember.js app that I would like to use jquery ui's sortable widget on. My view looks like

```
<ul id="sort-container">
{{#each content}}
    <li>{{title}}</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

Sorting works fine, until one of the bindings needs to update. The problem is that each `<li>` gets surrounded by ember's infamous metamorph `<script>` tags. See the actual DOM generated in this image

[image: DOM]

Is there an *easy* way to make these two play nicely together?

Is there a way to force the view to repaint? I could easily implement that after the sortable `deactivate` event is fired.

Comment: a view can be repaint by calling rerender() on it. But keep in mind that the metamorphs are responsible of the bindings stuff. So removing them seems to be a bad smell. Could you provide a jsfiddle witch illustrate the problem ?

Comment: @sly7_7 Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wmarbut/8VMdz/. To exemplify the problem first just run it and click the link to remove an item. Then re-run, change the order more than once, and click the link to remove an item. It will sometimes remove 2 or all because the metamorphs no longer line up with the `<li>` that they were binding

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems to me that using Ember.CollectionView, could solve this. So I gave a try. It seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/8ahjd/

handlebars:

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {{view App.JQuerySortableView content=model}}
  <a {{action removeItem}}>Remove Second Item</a>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name='jquery-sortable-item'>
  {{view.content.title}}
</script>
```

javascript:

```js
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.ApplicationController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  removeItem: function() {
    this.removeAt(1);        
  }            
});

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return [
      {id: 1, title:'Test 1'},
      {id: 2, title:'Test 2'},
      {id: 3, title:'Test 3'}
    ];
  }
});

App.JQuerySortableItemView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'jquery-sortable-item'        
});

App.JQuerySortableView = Ember.CollectionView.extend({
    tagName: 'ul',
    itemViewClass: App.JQuerySortableItemView, 

    didInsertElement: function(){
        this._super();
        this.$().sortable().disableSelection();
    }
});
```

​

Comment: That's the ticket... With all the help you've given me I feel like I need a bat signal for you or something (or perhaps that's what the emberjs tag is). Thanks!

Comment: interesting to see that hosted at `http://cdn.shopify.com/` considering that they have their own competing MVC js framework called... wait for it... *batman.js*

Comment: Why does this work? CollectionView doesn't use metamorphs? If that's the case, how does it handle bindings?

Comment: @elsurudo Using the collection view removes only the enclosing metamorphs of the items, whose conflict with jquery ui. See this updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/eYBtn/