# Ember Js Remove Metamorph code

Tags: ember.js

I am currently in a situation where i need to remove the metamorph tags used in a ember js select box. I use a JS plugin that takes my select box and turns it into a styled select box which i have customized using css.

I currently have this ember js select box in my view.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="opportunities">
{{view Ember.Select 
             contentBinding="controller.filter" 
             optionLabelPath="content.metacode"  
             optionValuePath="content.description" 
             class="mydds opportunitylistcategory"}}
</script>
```

I just need a way to remove the metamorph code but for ember selectbox to still have binding etc enabled... I have read about removing metamorphic data with a jquery sortable but that hasnt helped me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you simply can't do that, as Ember needs metamorphs in order to make bindings stuff work. I'm curious of what plugin do you use, usually, I think the <script> tags are not a problem. Would it be possible to write a jsfiddle with the concerned plugins/libs ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i use jQuery MSDropDown with ember but the script tags break this plugin. I need a selectbox plugin that works well with ember that i can fully style with css.

Comment: Technically you should be able to style `Ember.Select`. In regards to the metamorph, if your select doesn't need to be re-rendered after the first time (if the data doesn't change once it's rendered), you could try to use the `{{unbound}}` helper block (not sure if it made master yet) by EvilTrout, but that would require some extra code since that select is actually a `View`.

Comment: unbound is in master i believe, if you go that route you probably won't be able to use the select view.

Comment: Well, i use the js plugin so that i can completely hide the select box and add my own arrows etc. I tried adding a normal html select and then generating the options with an ember js {{#each}} but this still adds script tags and breaks the plugin. Is there a way to use a ember js {{#each}} but to use unbound. I tried unbound on the values that it spits out but this doesnt work.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to work around this is to use an Ember.CollectionView.

I've run into this issue with a simple unordered list (`<ul><li>`).

Here is an answer that demonstrates how to do it https://stackoverflow.com/a/11749736/701368

---

**Edit**

The original answer was for a version of Ember before 1.0.

I would recommend using the `{{each}}` helper with the `itemViewClass` attribute when dealing with newer versions of Ember.js. You can find the documentation here: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#toc_specifying-a-view-class-for-items.

So don't use the block level helper; you want to use `{{each}}` instead of `{{#each}}`.